# Armar query con DB Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

tengo un query en mi contrador y necesito obtener las edades de las personas, pero en rango de 10, y no se como hacer dicha accion.  mi query es el siguiente

```
$edad=DB::table("view_usuarios")
        ->join('usuarios_pasos', 'view_usuarios.id', 'usuarios_pasos.usuario_id')
        ->select(
            'view_usuarios.id' , 
            DB::raw("round(avg(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(now(),view_usuarios.fecha_nac)))) as edad")
        )
        ->groupBy("view_usuarios.id")
        ->orderBy("view_usuarios.id")
        ->get();
```

La idea es que me entregue la cantidad
0-10 = 16,
11-20= 20,
etc,

como hacer lo que necesito hacer, por favor, ayuda, ya que esta información debo llevarla a un gráfico y no sé como sacar rangos de edad

Comment: En eloquent o con los query builders también puedes usar [los limit y los offset](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#limit-and-offset)

Comment: @gaidyjg pero lo que necesito es que me diga cuantos usuarios hay 0-10 años = 15, de 11 - 20 años = 19, etc, ya que eso debo llevarlo a un gráfico

Comment: @Karli entonces debes sumar y agrupar basado en condiciones, revisa la documentación de Laravel para construir cases y por ahi va la respuesta junto con el uso de count

Comment: @BetaM, gracias por la sugerencia, veré la documentacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrias que utilizar la condicional del "whereBetween", rango [min, max]

```
$edad=DB::table("view_usuarios")
            ->join('usuarios_pasos', 'view_usuarios.id', 'usuarios_pasos.usuario_id')
            ->select(
                'view_usuarios.id' , 
                DB::raw("round(avg(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(now(),view_usuarios.fecha_nac)))) as edad")
            )
            ->whereBetween('edad', [0, 10])
            ->groupBy("view_usuarios.id")
            ->orderBy("view_usuarios.id")
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos formas de abordar esto, si quieres hacerlo de manera automática, debes construir el query con un `for`, primero hallar la edad más alta para saber cuál será el límite y así, construir un query string. O sino, simplemente defines los rangos manualmente, lo cual facilitaría las cosas.

1. De manera automática:

   ```
   $byRange = 10;

   $olderBirthday = DB::table('view_usuarios')->min('fecha_nac');

   $age = Carbon::parse($olderBirthday)->age;

   $olderAge = (int)($age/10)*10 + $byRange;

   $queryString = "SELECT CASE ";

   for($i = 0; $i < $olderAge; $i = $i + $byRange) {
      $from = $i;
      $to = (int)($i/10)*10 + $byRange;
      if($i == 0) $i++;
      $queryString .= "WHEN fecha_nac BETWEEN {$from} AND {$to} THEN '{$from} - {$to}' ";
   }

    $queryString .= " ELSE {$olderAge + 1}+ END AS range FROM view_usuarios";
   ```

Eso generará una query de la siguiente manera, que es lo que necesitas:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN fecha_nac BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN '0 - 10'
         WHEN fecha_nac BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11 - 20'
         WHEN fecha_nac BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21 - 30'
         WHEN fecha_nac BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31 - 40'
         WHEN fecha_nac BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41 - 50'
         ELSE 'Mayores de 50'
       END AS range
FROM   view_usuarios
```

Lo único que queda es construir la query. Puedes utilizar `fromSub()` ya que obtendrás los datos de una subquery.

```
$results = DB::select('a.range', DB::raw('count(*) as `cantidad`'))
    ->fromSub($queryString, 'a')
    ->groupBy('a.range')
    ->get();
```